# How can I map elements when props are also passed?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, mapping, material-ui

I am using a bunch of text fields in my code and I want to map them instead of writing them multiple times. However, I am unable to do since my textfields also require elements from the constructor props.

```
import React, { Component, useState } from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import PermanentDrawerLeft from '../../components/drawer/drawer';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';

export default class AddUserPage extends Component <{}, { firstName: string, lastName: string, email: string,phone: string,password: string }>{
  constructor(props: Readonly<{}>) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      firstName: '',
      lastName: '',
      phone: '',
      email: '',
      password: '',
    };
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div>
     <PermanentDrawerLeft></PermanentDrawerLeft>
     <div className='main-content'>
     <form className="form" noValidate autoComplete="off">

     {

       <TextField id="outlined-basic" label="First Name" variant="outlined" onChange={e => {
                this.setState({firstName: e.target.value})
              }}/>
     </form>
     </div>
   </div>
    );
  }
}
```

If I use the follow mapping:

```
     {
              [{ label: 'First Name', state: this.state.firstName }].map((item, index) => (
                <TextField
                  id="outlined-basic"
                  label={item.label}
                  variant="outlined"
                  onChange={e => this.setState({ [item.state]: e.target.value })}
                />
              ))
            }
```

I get this error on the last line:

```
Argument of type '{ [x: string]: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{
```

Code Sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-cray-o87fm?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see few syntax issues with your second snippet:

- you shouldn't wrap `firstName` into curly braces within object literal (`[{label: 'First Name', state: 'firstName'}]`)
- for dynamic object property, you should wrap that into square braces, like that: `this.setState({[item.state]: e.target.value})`
- also, you got closing square bracket missing within source array

So, the code you should've been trying out would look something, like:

```
{
    [{label: "First Name", state: 'firstName'}].map(item, index) => (
        <TextField
          id="outlined-basic"
          key={index}
          label={item.label}
          variant="outlined"
          onChange={e => this.setState({[item.state]: e.target.value} as any)}
        />
    ))
}
```

*p.s.* those are conclusions I can make without seeing wider code context

Comment: This doens't exactly work, could you see the code in my updated qs? If I wrote, state: firstName, i got the error that name firstName not found. So I changed it to this.state.firstName but that doesn't work either

Comment: That was just for information. I fixed the firstName not found issue but I am still getting the one mentioned in the updated qs

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-cray-o87fm?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: Nope, that doesn't work either. Could you maybe try it here on this codesandbox. Thanks!

Comment: @x89 : with slight changes it [renders perfectly fine](https://si5w6.csb.app/) - no errors, no issues. Check the forked [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/snowy-cache-si5w6?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark).